# What is the shortcut to build and run a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there a shortcut that builds and run a project in the debug mode in the Visual Studio?

For example, `Ctrl+Shift+B` makes a build, but it does not run the program.

Comment: Switching mode and starting debugging are two different actions.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that builds and runs in the CURRENT configuration; and does not force debug

Comment: @UKMonkey Ctrl+Shift+B does not switch configuration either (I'm not sure why OP says Ctrl+Alt+B, which shows breakpoints in debug mode).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, typo corrected.